# sql server 2008 query help required

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table structure:

```
 ProductID  ProductName ParentId
    13       Test            NULL
    NULL     Test1           14
    13       Test2           14
    14       Test4           15 
    NULL     Test5           16
```

Now I want to retrieve result based on Parentid like

- Scenario 1: for Parentid 14 I want row with productid=13
- Scenario 2: for Parentid=15 I want row with productid=14
- Scenario 3: -for Parentid=16 I want row with productid is null

Please help me to do this

output should be

if I pass `parentid = 14` then o/p

```
13       Test2  14
```

if I pass `parentid = 15` then

```
14       Test4  15
```

if I pass `parented = 16` then

```
NULL     Test5  16
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: What you mean by `if I pass`? are you going to pass the parameter to a stored procedure?

Comment: parentid is input parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement in `WHERE` condition like

```
select ProductID,
  ProductName,
  ParentId
FROM products
WHERE ISNULL(ProductID,0) = CASE 
                  WHEN ParentId = 14 THEN 13 
                  WHEN ParentId = 15 THEN 14
                  ELSE 0 
                  END
```

Comment: your query is doubt correct! But for every new ID user will need to update the query and deploy. I would not vote it as of now.. sorry!

Comment: @Murtaza, that may be but I am just going by what has been specified in problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.here parentid is used as input parameter.Finally I made the below query:-
Select top 1* from test where isnull(productid,0) in
(
select isnull(productid,0) from test
)
and parentid=16 order by productid desc

Comment: @user3729777, you should clarify that in post beforehand. if you are passing `parentid` as parameter then you can just do like `select * FROM products WHERE ISNULL(ParentId,0) = @ParentId`. Also, consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Comment: @rahul if parentid is 14 then your query returns two rows and I want row which have productid value.

Comment: @user3729777, that was just an example. What I meant that you can do something like `select * FROM products WHERE ISNULL(ProductID,0) = (select ISNULL(ProductID,0) from products where ParentId = @ParentId`

Answer (score 0):

As per the Question and scenario's I have made an assumption to display the records with input parameters for ParentID

[SQL DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/822d5/18)

```
SELECT t.* FROM tabletest t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t1.ProductId 
              FROM tabletest t1 
              WHERE ISNULL(t1.ProductID, '') = ISNULL(t.ProductID, ''))
AND ParentID = 14

SELECT t.* FROM tabletest t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t1.ProductId 
              FROM tabletest t1 
              WHERE ISNULL(t1.ProductID, '') = ISNULL(t.ProductID, ''))
AND ParentID = 15

SELECT t.* FROM tabletest t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t1.ProductId 
              FROM tabletest t1 
              WHERE ISNULL(t1.ProductID, '') = ISNULL(t.ProductID, ''))
AND ParentID = 16
```

I am not sure if this is the correct implementation of the queries, but as per the question it will sever the purpose the get the data.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
SELECT ProductID,ProductName,ParentId
FROM products
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductId FROM products WHERE ParentId = 14);

SELECT ProductID,ProductName,ParentId
FROM products
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductId FROM products WHERE ParentId = 15);

SELECT ProductID,ProductName,ParentId
FROM products
WHERE ISNULL(ProductID,'') IN (SELECT ISNULL(ProductId,'') FROM products WHERE ParentId = 16);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2511c/5)